# Log daily returns of multiple securities for multiple time period in R

Tags: equities, r, log-returns, quantmod

I have dataset containing daily closing prices of 5413 companies from 2000 to 2014. I want to calculate daily log returns for the stocks as according to dates as log(Price today/Price yesterday). I illustrate the dataset as follows:

```
Date       A G L    ABA    ABB ABBEY 
2000-1-3    NA      NA      NA  NA
2000-1-4    79.5    325     NA  961  
2000-1-5    79.5    322.5   NA  945
2000-1-6    79.5    327.5   NA  952
2000-1-7    NA      327.5   NA  941  
2000-1-10   79.5    327.5   NA  946
2000-1-11   79.5    327.5   NA  888
```

How could calculate the the daily log returns and additionally tackle the NA. My sample period is from 2000 to 2014 so there are some companies who were listed in year 2001,so, for the whole year 2000 they have NA, how should this be handled. Your help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, it wasn't easy because you didn't mentioned how your data is formatted. I create my own `data.frame()` basing on data you provided. 
You can skip this part if your data.frame is ready. Here's code I used to create a dataframe:

```
> #given dates
> dates=c("2000-1-3","2000-1-4","2000-1-5","2000-1-6","2000-1-7","2000-1-10","2000-1-11")
> #formating from string to dates
> newdates=as.Date(dates,"%Y-%m-%d")
> #given stock prices
> stock1prices=c("NA","79.5","79.5","79.5","NA","79.5", "79.5")
> stock2prices=c("NA", "325", "322.5", "327.5", "327.5", "327.5", "327.5")
> stock3prices=c("NA","NA","NA","NA","NA","NA","NA")
> stock4prices=c("NA","961","945","952","941","946","888")
> #NewStockPrces - converting from string to numbers
> nsp1=as.numeric(stock1prices)
> nsp2=as.numeric(stock2prices)
> nsp3=as.numeric(stock3prices)
> nsp4=as.numeric(stock4prices)
> #creating dataframe of prices
> prices=data.frame(newdates,nsp1,nsp2,nsp3,nsp4)
> prices
    newdates nsp1  nsp2 nsp3 nsp4
1 2000-01-03   NA    NA   NA   NA
2 2000-01-04 79.5 325.0   NA  961
3 2000-01-05 79.5 322.5   NA  945
4 2000-01-06 79.5 327.5   NA  952
5 2000-01-07   NA 327.5   NA  941
6 2000-01-10 79.5 327.5   NA  946
7 2000-01-11 79.5 327.5   NA  888
```

There was just 4 stocks, so I used very simple method to create my dataframe *prices*. **Here's what is more important for you.**

```
logs=data.frame(
+   cbind.data.frame(
+     newdates[-1],
+     diff(as.matrix(log(prices[,-1])))
+     )
+   )
> logs
  newdates..1. nsp1         nsp2 nsp3         nsp4
1   2000-01-04   NA           NA   NA           NA
2   2000-01-05    0 -0.007722046   NA -0.016789481
3   2000-01-06    0  0.015384919   NA  0.007380107
4   2000-01-07   NA  0.000000000   NA -0.011621895
5   2000-01-10   NA  0.000000000   NA  0.005299429
6   2000-01-11    0  0.000000000   NA -0.063270826
```

To clarify what is going on in this code lets analyze it from the inside out:
**Step 1: Calculating log-returns**

- You know that `log(a/b) = log(a)-log(b)`, so we can calculate
  differences of logarithms. Funcition `diff(x,lag=1)` calculates
  differences with given lag. Here it is `lag=1` so it gives first
  differences.
- Our `x` are prices in dataframe. Do pick from a
  `data.frame` every columns without the first (there are dates) we use
  `prices[,-1]`.
- We need logarithms, so `log(prices[,-1])`
- Function `diff()` works with vector or matrix, so we need to treat
  calculated logarithms as matrix, thus
  `as.matrix(log(prices[,-1]))
- Now we can use `diff()` with `lag=1`, so `diff(as.matrix(log(prices[,-1])))`

**Step 2: Creating dataframe of log-returns and dates**

- We can't use just `cbind()`. Firstly, because lengths are different (returns are shorter by 1 record). We need to remove first date, so `newdates[-1]`
- Secondly, using cbind() dates will be transformed into numeric values such 160027 or other. 
   Here we have to use `cbind.data.frame(x,y)`, as seen above.
- Now data is ready and we can create use a `data.frame()` and name it as logs so `logs=data.frame(...)` as above.

Once again I don't know how your database looks like, so I can't give you exact solution. Most important thing is to use `diff(log(x))` to easily calculate log-returns.

Comment: Thank you again. Just added a minor detail and it works logs=data.frame(cbind.data.frame(Date$Price[-1],diff(as.matrix(log(Price[,-1])))))